# Batch file: Run specific part on particular OS

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a script with the purpose of creating a scheduled task on either a W2K3 or W2K12 server (more to be added later on) depending on the target server. I won't create separate scripts for each server type as this is already a part of a bundle of installation scripts that need to be distributed via a single package.
There are different users for the servers.
I have tried the following, but **both** jobs are created on each server type, with the one being redundant as it does not fit. I only want **one** scheduled task to be created dependent on the server type.
I'm a bit blind for the moment on how to solve it, also it would be great to avoid using "goto". I would appreciate your take on it.

```
setlocal
set runlevel=

for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v "CurrentVersion"') do set os_ver=%%j

if /i "%os_ver:~,1%" EQU "5.2" (
set runlevel=/rl HIGHEST goto W2K3
exit
)
else
(
if /i "%os_ver:~,1%" GEQ "6.2" (
set runlevel=/rl HIGHEST goto W2K12
exit
)
)

:W2K3
schtasks.exe /create /tn "Files Handler W2K3" /sc DAILY /TR "D:\TMP_DONT_DELETE\Files_Handler.bat" /ST 05:30 /ru User1 /rp epicfun %runlevel%


:w2K12
schtasks.exe /create /tn "Files Handler W2K12" /sc DAILY /TR "D:\TMP_DONT_DELETE\Files_Handler.bat" /ST 05:30 /ru User2 /rp newkidontheblock %runlevel%
```

Comment: Despite the fact that there are several errors in your provided code, it is more important to mention that as far as I remember, the [tag:schtasks.exe] run level, `/RL`, option is not available in [tag:windows-server-2003].

Comment: In addition to that you may have issues with using that registry key value too. I have found that several [tag:windows-10] systems have a `CurrentVersion` string value of `6.3`, which would not be different to having a [tag:windows-server-2012-r2] or [tag:windows-8.1] system.

Comment: My script works just fine on W2K3, and on W2K12 for that matter, but I know that the CurrentVersion values can vary. This is something I can adjust very easily.

Comment: [This Microsoft page for Schtasks.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks), specifically states that the following options are not available in Windows 2003, `/RI`, `/ET`, `/DU`, `/K`, `/EC`, `/IT`, `/NP`, `/Z`, `/XML`, `/V1`, `/F`, `/RL`, and `/DELAY`; but hey, if it works for you, Microsoft must be wrong!

Comment: There is no way your existing code works.  The `ELSE` cannot be on a separate line from the parentheses.

Comment: The expression `%os_ver:~,1%` returns the first character of the content of variable `os_ver`, which can never equal a string consisting of three characters…

Comment: …and there I was thinking it was just Microsoft and myself that were wrong! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea using [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) instead of the registry, to get your required version number. This additionally filters the results to only those with a product type of 3, (Server).

```batch-file
@SetLocal EnableExtensions
@Set "strVer="
@For /F "EOL=V Tokens=1-2 Delims=." %%G In (
    '%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe OS Where "ProductType='3'" Get Version'
) Do @Set /A "strVer=%%G%%H" 2>NUL
@If Not Defined strVer GoTo :EOF
@If %strVer% Equ 52 (%__AppDir__%schtasks.exe /Create /RU User1 /RP epicfun^ 
 /SC DAILY /TN "Files Handler W2K3" /TR "D:\TMP_DONT_DELETE\Files_Handler.bat"^
 /ST 05:30) Else If %strver% Equ 62 %__AppDir__%schtasks.exe /Create /RU User2^
 /RP newkidontheblock /SC DAILY /TN "Files Handler W2K12"^
 /TR "D:\TMP_DONT_DELETE\Files_Handler.bat" /ST 05:30 /RL HIGHEST
```

*I have removed the `/RL` option from the Windows 2003 `SchTasks` command because Microsoft says it isn't available in that OS, feel free to put it back in, if you don't believe them.*

Answer (score 0):

Put an `goto :EOF` statement after the :W2K3 schtasks.exe statement and remove `%runlevel%` because it's not supported as noted in Compo's answer:

```
...

:W2K3
schtasks.exe /create /tn "Files Handler W2K3" /sc DAILY /TR "D:\TMP_DONT_DELETE\Files_Handler.bat" /ST 05:30 /ru User1 /rp epicfun
goto :EOF

...
```

Comment: It should be `exit /B` or `goto :EOF` in order just to quit the batch script, because `exit` also terminates the hosting `cmd.exe` instance…

Comment: …and please note my comments, which show that the `/RL` option is not available in Windows 2003.